# Create a multi column bar chart using d3.js

Tags: d3.js

Currently, I am learning the d3.js library and I started to wonder whether it is possible to create a multiple column horizontal bar chart as shown below. The visual shown below was created in Tableau.

[image: Multiple Column Bar Horizontal Bar Chart]

I don't have any code to show since I am very new at it.

Edit: Adding Sample Data For Reference

```
id,country_name,value 1,value 2 actual,value 2 planned,value 3 actual,value 3 planned
1,Germany,3,6,9,12,12
1,China,5,9,14,6,18
1,India,4,14,19,14,15
1,Netherlands,5,7,1,11,7
1,Russia,3,7,11,7,11
1,Saudi Arabia,3,12,8,7,11
1,United States,3,2,20,8,2
2,Croatia,2,1,14,3,16
2,Brazil,4,2,20,6,4
2,Bulgaria,1,15,9,9,13
2,Germany,1,13,12,14,17
2,China,5,3,5,1,12
2,India,4,6,7,8,15
2,Singapore,1,13,20,1,6
3,Russia,5,14,18,4,17
3,Saudi Arabia,4,10,16,1,3
3,United States,1,3,4,8,3
3,Croatia,5,11,15,4,3
3,Brazil,1,1,13,4,8
3,Bulgaria,3,15,14,15,7
3,Germany,3,11,12,3,8
4,China,5,12,13,14,12
5,India,4,1,10,3,17
5,Singapore,3,15,14,5,4
5,Canada,3,10,7,12,18
5,Saudi Arabia,1,1,17,3,8
4,Canada,3,15,6,8,3
4,Qatar,1,8,16,14,20
4,Brazil,3,12,11,12,11
4,Bulgaria,2,5,4,13,18
4,Canada,3,11,20,13,13
5,China,4,9,7,9,8
```

Comment: The easiest ist doing it with some lines of code with https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/plot (this is build on top of d3.js)

Comment: Just build 3 simple charts with `axisBottom` and add `axisLeft` separately

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky I would highly appreciate it if you can show me some example code.

Comment: @iLoveYou3000 can you post your sample data?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky added sample data in question

Comment: There is a problem with your data: some countries are listed twice or more (with different ids and 5 values for each data item). In the chart, each country is shown once. How to treat the duplicated data items?